Java - Why can't i take an array of a superclass, and get the subclass functions?
I'm trying to write a Chess Program from scratch. I have a superclass called "Piece", and subclasses for all the individual chess pieces (Pawn, Bishop, Knight, ect). I also have another class "Board" which stores a Piece[][] with all the information on which type of piece is where.
For example:
private Piece[][] board = new Piece[][]{
    {new Rook(-1, 7,0),new Knight(-1, 7, 1),new Bishop(-1, 0, 0),new Queen(-1,7,3),new King(-1,7,4),new Bishop(-1,7,5),new Knight(-1,7,6),new Rook(-1,7,7)},
    {new Pawn(-1,6,0),new Pawn(-1,6,1),new Pawn(-1,6,2),new Pawn(-1,6,3),new Pawn(-1,6,4),new Pawn(-1,6,5),new Pawn(-1,6,6),new Pawn(-1,6,7)},
    {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
    {null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null},
    {new Piece(1,1,1,0),new Pawn(1,1,1),new Pawn(1,1,2),new Pawn(1,1,3),new Pawn(1,1,4),new Pawn(1,1,5),new Pawn(1,1,6),new Pawn(1,1,7)},
    {new Rook(1,0,0),new Knight(1,0,1),new Bishop(1,0,2),new Queen(1,0,3),new King(1,0,4),new Bishop(1,0,5),new Knight(1,0,6),new Rook(1,0,7)}};


syntax for pieces is (int Color, int Rank, int File). Color is an int because of the way the code determines piece value.
I'm sure there's a better way to do the board, but I would rather not refactor that part of the code at the moment.
My problem currently lies in the functions where I am checking the validity of a move. The Board class takes care of the stuff that applies to all the classes, but then to finalize the check, it calls the function Valid() in the class of the piece, where it stores the code where it checks whether the given move is allowed by the movement rules of the piece. However, when I try to call this method, instead of returning the method within the subclass, it tries to return the valid() method in the Piece class instead of the respective type of piece.
I am in the process of refactoring my code to not be dependent on several more if() statements than is required, by keeping piece-specific information within their own classes, but this is turning out to be more unhelpful than expected. The code worked before, and I could revert to that older version, but I would like to continue this refactor in order to ease my potential workload in the future.
Currently my code looks like this:
switch(board[7-rank][file].getType()){
      case 1: Pawn p = (Pawn)board[7-rank][file];return p.valid();
      case 2: Bishop b = (Bishop)board[7-rank][file];return b.valid();
      case 3: Knight n = (Knight)board[7-rank][file];return n.valid();
      case 4: Rook r = (Rook)board[7-rank][file];return r.valid();
      case 5: Queen q = (Queen)board[7-rank][file];return q.valid();
      case 6: King k = (King)board[7-rank][file];return k.valid();
      default: System.out.println("Data returned as Piece, returning false.");return false;
    }

For reference, the getType() function is a Superclass method designed to return an integer value that represents the piece. I feel from my naming scheme it is obvious which number corresponds to which piece. This function works as intended.
Currently the code is running, up until running the prior segment of code where it returns that class Piece cannot be cast to class Pawn (Piece and Pawn are in unnamed module of loader com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.MemoryClassLoader @68b32e3e).
I have also tried forgoing the casting, which ended up in a similar result. (Type mismatch, cannot convert from piece to pawn.).
I believe the problem lies in how i am instantiating the board, as I am instantiating it as a Piece[][], but I am unsure how to get the result I want.

Maybe also include Piece and at least one child class (ie Pawn) - valid should be a method of Piece which is then overridden by the children, there by removing the need to do any kind of casting

apparently there is a Piece in the array, whose getType() is returning 1 (assuming the error is at the line with case 1) - much probably the new Piece(1,1,1,0) (by symmetry, I would expect new Pawn(1,1,0))

suggestions: 1) make it abstract class Piece (or interface), it should not be instantiated; 2) add valid(), eventually abstract, to Piece (as suggested in first comment,) casting often indicates a deficient object model

I would suggest that you favor composition over inheritance and convert Peace into an interface. You wouldn't need the switch anymore, just call piece.valid().

Piece shouldn't know anything about its subclasses. Convert Piece to an interface and start from there. Don't store each piece's location in the piece itself - that's what the Board is for. Make your isValid() method take "from location" and "to location" parameters, and maybe add a canJump() method etc. Separate concerns and decouple.

I think there is a better way to check what a Piece might be and the way to check is by the keyword 'instanceof' checking if a Piece might a rook or pawn, etc. If you iterate though the array you can check
if (board[7-rank][file] instanceof Pawn){ // do something}

And then you can check this for every single piece. This may require 5 if statements and one else statement but this might fix your polymorphism issue. Also consider using a loop to check this for every possible step. [This is a bit extra but don't try to check for every single legal moves using nested loops instead use recursion but good luck!]
